# Using values from list into a sub function

Tags: python, list

I am running a function that produces a list like this:

```
rft_id_list = []
for i in payload_df_rft:
    payload_rft = json.dumps(i)
    url = 'https://domain/api/link/rft'
    print(url)
    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=payload_rft)
    rft_script_output = response.json()
    # print(rft_script_output)
    rft_id = (rft_script_output['id'])
    #print(rft_id)
    rft_id_list.append(rft_id)
    print(rft_id_list)
    print('~~~Script Finished ~~~')
```

Script above gives me the values below:

```
['1234abc', '22345bcde', '33456cdef']
```

Next sub-function has a url and I want the `rft_id_list` to iterate through the values above and add them to the URL while doing a PUT.

```
url = 'https://domain/api/link/' + rft_id_list
```

What's the best way I can do this?

Comment: What is stopping you from writing another loop?

Comment: "What's the best way I can do this?" - you've just described it: "iterate through the values above [iterate over `rft_id_list`] and add them to the URL while doing a PUT". What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Ugh, I feel like stupid now.  I just had to add one line and some tabs to fix this.  Answer was right in front of me lol.  Thank you so much.  Y'all are awesome.

Comment: The `list` `join` method method allows you to do concatenate in a single call.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to look into it, and see if doing it in a single call would work.